# Foreign key constraints and bridging tables

Tags: mysql

I am currently working with 6 tables: `users`, `categories`, `videogames`, `videogames_categories_bridge`, `users_favorites`, `users_dislikes`. I am trying to layout the tables in the best manner possible to show video games preference for user(see below example). However, I am getting a foreign key constraint error when creating the tables. How could I achieve(if possible) the below with my current tables schema? Also, Is there a way in avoiding that both values inserted(`favorite` and `dislike`) are marked `true` for a `game`? [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1fc8ba)

Example: Show all video game preference for an `userid 569723`

```
game_id  category_id   game_name               category_name    favorite    dislike
-------  -----------   ----------------        -------------    ---------   --------
840832      1000     'counter-strike'               fps             1         NULL
779343      1000     'call of duty modern warfare'  fps             1         NULL
684244      2000     'minecraft'                  adventure        NULL       NULL
983565      2000     'assassin\'s creed syndicate'adventure        NULL       NULL
858168      3000     'need for speed - rivals'    racing           NULL       NULL
819837      4000     'mortal kombat x'           fighting          NULL       NULL
634266      5000     'street fighter v'          fighting          NULL       NULL
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some problems with your foreign keys and tables in general:

- the "destination" column of the foreign key reference has to be indexed so InnoDB can quickly check if it exists etc. (for instance `user_id` in your `users` table is only a second column in your primary key, it has to be first in some index)
- in one case (`videogames_categories_bridge.category_id`) you try to reference the same column in the same table, that does not make sense
- primary keys in `users` and `categories` contain the name AND id at the same time so they do not enforce much - usually the ID is the right one for a foreign key. The way you defined it there might be the same id for multiple different names.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e24b - the FKs modified to work